# Android CircularReveal bug: Not working after starting another type of animator on the same view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, circularreveal

I have an app with a RecyclerView and in each item I implemented Swipe to star/dismiss behavior using onTouch(). There's no problem with my implementation and I can handle right and left swipe and claim drag from RecyclerView.

Each item is RevealFrameLayout that consists of content on the top, and below there is the original layout and the layout to be revealed, just like this:

Top layout:

[image: Top layout:]

Below layout (top revealed layer):

[image: Below layout (top revealed layer):]

Below layout (default layout before reveal):

[image: Below layout (default layout before reveal):]

There I reveal the top revealed layers (colored ones) and everything works, until I added another ObjectAnimator to hide the star layout (make starred/unstarred), when The reveal works for the first time, and then another swipe will execute the hide animator, then 3rd time, where it's supposed to reveal once again, it really starts the animation (by debugging start() is executed) but it doesn't show up. 4th time the hiding animator works but no revealed layout.

[image: Behavior gif:]

The method to trigger any action:

```java
void triggerAction(SwipeAction swipeAction, final Note note, final int position) {
    if (swipeAction.getActionId() == SwipeAction.STAR) {
        if (note.isStarred() && !hidden && !hideAnimating && !justAnimated) {
            starActionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            archiveActionLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Animator hideAnim = AnimationUtils.createHideAnimation(revealStar);
            hideAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    revealStar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    hideAnimating = false;
                    hidden = true;
                    note.setStarred(false);
                    MainActivity.notesController.set(position, note);
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
            hideAnim.start();
            revealStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // DEBUG: Only to make sure the star layout is shown.
            justAnimated = true;
            hideAnimating = true;
            revealAnimating = false;
            revealed = false;
            hidden = false;
        } else if (!note.isStarred() && !revealAnimating && !revealed && !justAnimated) {
            starActionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            archiveActionLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            final ObjectAnimator revealAnim = (ObjectAnimator) AnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(revealStar, (int) getCenterX(starActionImage), (int) getCenterY(starActionImage), 0, (float) getRadius(starActionLayout));
            revealAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    revealAnimating = false;
                    revealed = true;
                    note.setStarred(true);
                    MainActivity.notesController.set(position, note);
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
            revealAnim.start();
            justAnimated = true;
            revealAnimating = true;
            hideAnimating = false;
            hidden = false;
            revealed = false;
            revealStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else if (swipeAction.getActionId() == SwipeAction.ARCHIVE) {
        if (!revealAnimating && !revealed) {
            int added = starActionLayout.getWidth();
            starActionLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            archiveActionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animator revealAnim = AnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(revealArchive, (int) getCenterX(archiveActionImage) + added, (int) getCenterY(archiveActionImage), 0, (float) getRadius(archiveActionLayout));
            revealAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    revealAnimating = false;
                    revealed = true;
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
            revealAnim.start();
            revealAnimating = true;
            revealArchive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

There's no problem with my conditions as debugging shows that the reveal animator show code is executed when it should. And `AnimationUtils` is a custom class that wraps `ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(params)` and another custom ObjectAnimator `createHideAnimator()` and there's no problem with that too.

`AnimationUtils.java`:

```java
package com.skaldebane.util.graphics;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewAnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

public class AnimationUtils {

    public static Animator createCircularReveal(View view, int centerX, int centerY, float startRadius, float endRadius) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) return ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, centerX, centerY, startRadius, endRadius);
        else return io.codetail.animation.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, centerX, centerY, startRadius, endRadius);
    }

    public static Animator createHideAnimation(View view) {
        ObjectAnimator hideAnim = new ObjectAnimator();
        hideAnim.setPropertyName("alpha");
        hideAnim.setFloatValues(1.0F, 0.0F);
        hideAnim.setDuration(300);
        hideAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        hideAnim.setTarget(view);
        return hideAnim;
    }

}
```

**Note:** Don't tell me to use ItemTouchHelper instead as that is not the subject of my question and it doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: I need an answer please it's really important for me to have this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. It was simple but hard to notice. When I was applying the hide animator it was setting alpha permanently to 0, which meant the view would never appear again. I only had to use `view.setAlpha(1.0F);` directly after calling `view.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);`.